# Unable to get the latest value added to Mysql table based on posted time

Tags: mysql

SELECT * FROM `discussion_comments` GROUP BY disc_id  ORDER BY posted_date DESC

I have table example like given below:

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
id int(11),
cname varchar(11),
posted_date date,
posted_time varchar(20)
);
```

with values like:

```
INSERT INTO example
VALUES 
(1,'abc','2015-03-26','04:25 PM'),
(1,'def','2015-03-27','04:30 PM'),
(2,'ghi','2015-03-11','02:25 AM'),
(2,'jkl','2015-03-15','12:25 PM');
```

and I am trying to get only the latest value added to the table for an `id` based on `posted_date` & `posted_time` fields.

The result I am trying to achieve is:

```
(1,'def','2015-03-27','04:30 PM')
(2,'jkl','2015-03-15','12:25 PM')
```

The query I tried is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `example GROUP BY id ORDER BY posted_date DESC
```

I am not getting the desired result. Where did I go wrong??

Comment: I would suggest you to have unique ids. Also you may store the date and time in a single column.. it would be more easier to handle date and time functions or sorting

Comment: I do have a auto increment primary key field other than the id I have specified in this example. @Matei Miha

Comment: It looks to me like you have a perfectly valid natural key formed on your first two columns, so no surrogate pk required. But I agree that date and time would normally be stored as datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways and one way is `left join`

```
select e1.* from example e1 
left join example e2 on e1.id = e2.id 
and e1.posted_date < e2.posted_date where e2.id is null;
```

Or `Uncorrelated Sub-query`

```
select e1.* from example e1 
join ( 
   select id,max(posted_date) as posted_date from example group by id 
)x 
on x.id = e1.id and x.posted_date = e1.posted_date ;
```

Comment: Why e2.id is null in where clause?? @Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: Run this query `select e1.*,e2.id as e2id from example e1 
left join example e2 on e1.id = e2.id 
and e1.posted_date < e2.posted_date` and see the result what you get.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to sort desc date + time

```
select * from (select * from example order by STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(posted_date,posted_time),'%Y-%m-%d%h:%i %p') desc) as xx group by id;
```

If you want to sort desc by just date

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from example order by posted_date desc) as ex group by id
```

IMHO storing as timestamp is better when dealing with date operations unless maybe you have more than one timestamp fields is same table.

Comment: This relies on an undocumented hack (unless you count the comments section of the relevant page of the manual)

Comment: @Sajeev C The earlier code I wrote was just for posted date . With your example data it worked correct. I have now updated the code to work with time also. Seems to work for me.